# ¿Como actualizar un Recyclerview sin que se mueva de la posición actual del scroll?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, recyclerview, android-recyclerview

En mi app tengo un recyclerview con 20 productos principales  y al momento de hacer scroll en la parte superior carga otros 20 productos, el problema es que al momento de actualizar el recyclerview   `adapterrecycler.notifyDataSetChanged();`  este cambia la posición del scroll dirigiéndome al inicio del recyclerview, necesito bloquear esta opción y que el scroll  no se mueva de la posición donde estoy.

Answer (score 1):

Si el elemento de la lista `RecyclerView` padre tiene la propiedad "wrap_content", Recyclerview calcula las alturas nuevamente y se desplaza hacia arriba.

Hay tres soluciones:

Establezca su altura en un valor constante como este:

```
layout_height = "100dp"
```

O

```
match_parent
```

Usar `StaggeredLridLayoutManager` como este:

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager (nuevo StaggeredGridLayoutManager (1, 
StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
```

Si desea cambiar elementos con animaciones, use el método `notifyItemChanged` en Fragment o Activity. No en la clase de Adaptador:

```
mRecyclerView.getAdapter (). notifyItemChanged (posición);
```

Y la tercera

```
// Save state
private Parcelable recyclerViewState;
recyclerViewState = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();

// Restore state
recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(recyclerViewState);
```

La tercera y la segunda solución es más eficiente y sugiero esas

Comment: Gracias amigo por tu respuesta ya había  implementado algo parecido a la segunda opción y funciono, pero no me convence del todo por las animaciones que hace al momento de desplazarse o travez al item #20